# Perl reading from file into hash

Tags: perl, hash

I would like to read the contents of a file into a hash structure. The header of the file should be the key in the hash structure, as well as the values being the content listed below each column.

The file that I am going to read from will look something like this.

```
Recv-Q Send-Q             Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port 
0      128                            *:111                           *:*      users:(("rpcbind",1268,8))
0      128                            *:53845                         *:*      users:(("rpc.statd",1404,9))
0      128                            *:22                            *:*      users:(("sshd",1577,3))
0      128                    127.0.0.1:631                           *:*      users:(("cupsd",1452,7))
0      100                    127.0.0.1:25                            *:*      users:(("master",1686,12))
```

I would like to have say **Port** as a key, containing the keys: **111**, **53845**, **22**, **631**, **25**. How would I go about in order to read this file into the hash in the structure that I outlined?

Comment: You need to determine how the lines will be split into fields. Just spaces? Colons? Fixed positions?
Then, you need to read the first record, and split it into an array of strings.
Finally, you read all the other records, splitting each into an array of values, and assigning them to hash values-- based on the keys you read in the array from the first line of the file.

Comment: I really have no clue in how to succeed at this task. I have only programmed simpler tasks reading from files, row by row. I do not know how to make the program aware that I want to use the first line headers as keys. I do know that I should use "tab" as a delimiter.

Comment: Look at the docs for 'split'. What is going to go _into_ your hash?

Comment: Basically, the hash should contain all the information present in this file. It should split on "tab" and in some cases ":" as well as using the headers: **Recv-Q**, **Send-Q**, **Local Address**, **Port**, **Peer Address** and **Port** as keys, pointing to values. The values should be the data listed below each of the keys in the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll offer you a basic starter for 10 on how to parse your data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 
my @header = split ( " ", <DATA> );

my %service_on;


while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $recvq, $sendq, $locaddr_port, $peeraddr_port, $thing ) = split;
    my ( $locaddr, $port ) = split ( ":", $locaddr_port ); 
    $service_on{$port} = $thing; 
} 

print Dumper \%service_on; 


__DATA__
Recv-Q Send-Q             Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port 
0      128                            *:111                           *:*      users:(("rpcbind",1268,8))
0      128                            *:53845                         *:*      users:(("rpc.statd",1404,9))
0      128                            *:22                            *:*      users:(("sshd",1577,3))
0      128                    127.0.0.1:631                           *:*      users:(("cupsd",1452,7))
0      100                    127.0.0.1:25                            *:*      users:(("master",1686,12))
```

You *can* do a 'named field' approach if you wish, but if your data format is consistent, it doesn't matter too much. Bear in mind that your data doesn't actually look like it's tab delimited - if it isn't, splitting on whitespace is easier... but it's also going to 'break' on `Peer Addr`.

If you want to go down that road, you need to look at [`slice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)s of a hash. However, that isn't going to work as you have a field without a header row, which might just be discarded if you do.

E.g.:

```
while ( <DATA> ) {
    my %fields;
    @fields{@header} = split; 
    my ( $locaddr, $port ) = split ( ":", $fields{$port_field} ); 
    print Dumper \%fields;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data is tab-delimited, as you mention in a comment above, you can use the `split` function to split a string (e.g. a line from a file) into an array of values. On most systems, if perl is installed properly, you can look at the documentation of that function with the command `perldoc -f split`.

```
# Read the first line of the file:
my $header = <$fh>;
chomp $header;
my @fields = split /\t/, $header;
#
# Then read the rest of the lines:
my %data;
while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    my @values = split /\t/, $line;
    @data{@fields} = @values;
    ... # do something with %data here
}
```

If your data is delimited some other way, you'll have to modify how you split each line into fields.